# sails.getDatastore is not a function

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm currently in the middle of upgrading our API from v0.12 of Sails to v1. Not the easiest task, but will be worth it.

The current problem I'm having, is converting our old "ModelName.query" calls to the new style, which is supposedly "sails.getDatastore". Great, fine.

Except, that when trying to do this in **config/bootstrap.js**, I constantly get the error "sails.getDatastore is not a function".

Yes, I am using the default **sails-hook-orm**, the **.sailsrc** has it turned on explicitly; and yes, I have **globals turned on**.

Is the problem that the function isn't registered until after bootstrap? Because that is not an option for us; bootstrap is validating our database schema before lift (custom code, using native queries), so our production servers fail to deploy if we missed a database update. It eliminates a ton of human error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for taking the 1.0 plunge!

I'm not sure what you mean by the "default" sails-hook-orm -- that hook is installed directly as a dependency on each Sails 1.0 project -- but I can almost guarantee that the version you're using is not correct.  I would do:

```
npm cache clean
npm install sails-hook-orm@beta
```

in your project to make sure you get the latest (currently v2.0.0-21).  It adds `getDatastore` to the app object [when it initializes](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-hook-orm/blob/master/lib/initialize.js#L519).

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy! It seems, I was in-fact using an older version of Waterline...

The new docs did not make it clear, that this was an older repo; I had assumed it was created for v1. 

I'm currently moving on, in a new set of problems (the primary key movement, deprecated types, etc). Thank you so much!

Comment: For clarity, what I meant by "default" sails-hook-orm, is that I had originally taken the old hook, and re-written it, so "ID" was forced as first column, and added a soft-delete "deletedAt". So, the ORM hook designed for Sails is "default" to me. Even if it isn't part of v1.

Comment: what is the alternative for v0.12?